# Flex/bison compile error on windows

Tags: visual-c++, bison, yacc, flex-lexer

i have a lex and yacc file which compiles fine on linux.
When i try to compile it on windows using Visual c++ using the lex.yy.c & y.tab.c files i get the following error:

```
program1.y(184) : error C2059: syntax error : '<'
```

line 184 is

```
#define YYLAST      95
```

Comment: That doesn't say much can you at least paste a few lines local to the error ?

Comment: It's line 184 in program1.y, not in y.tab.c.

Comment: There is only 100 lines in program1.y though. No files compile I have tried a few which all work on linux.

Comment: how about you paste your full source and we check it out

Comment: C++ has a `#line number filename` which modifies what line is reported through the compiler. Your probably not showing us the actual error line

Comment: please provide some more info.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how i build my files. I think --nounistd is what you need

```
bison --report=all -y -d ./test.y
flex --nounistd ./test.l
```